# Symbolic link for multiple file to single file

Tags: python, ubuntu, unix, logging, symlink

I have a scenario where I want to redirect logs of multiple files to same symlink.

 I have let's say three files `file1.log` `file2.log` and `file3.log`

`file1.log` has

```
This is file 1
```

`file2.log` has

```
This is file 2
```

`file3.log` has

```
This is file 3
```

Now I want to create symlink of all this file to `file.log`
such that content of `file.log` are

```
This is file 1
This is file 2
This is file 3
```

And this happens dynamically. i.e if the content of `file1.log` is modified then e.g `This line append to file1.log` then `file1.log` should show

```
This is file 1
This is file 2
This is file 3
This line append to file1.log
```

Is there any standard way of doing this? I have stuck here for quite some time.
I am using `ubuntu 18.04` and `python 3.6.9`
-----------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------
This are not all the files I have like 20 file with name `file*.log` and there can be multiple files like `f1X.log` `f2X.log` which needs to be redirected to `f1.log` , `f2.log`

Comment: There's no way to do this with symbolic links. A symlink simply points to one other filename.

Comment: Do you need to keep all the `fileX.log` files separate?

Comment: If not, you could just make them all symlinks to `file.log`. So when a program writes to `file1.log`, it's actually writing to `file.log`, and the same for programs logging to `file2.log`.

Comment: @Barmar yes I want to keep all `fileX.log` separate as they are autogenerated where `X` is a timestamp. I have multiple files like `f1X.log`, `f2X.log` etc. where `X` is the timestamp. Is there any alternative of symlink that I can use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from itertools import chain
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

log_path_list = [p for p in Path('.').glob('*.log') if p.name != 'file.log']
log = Path('file.log')

files = []
for log_path in log_path_list:
    files.append(log_path.open())
lines = chain(*map(lambda f: (line for line in f),files))
with log.open('w') as flog:
     for line in lines:
         flog.write(line)
     flog.flush()
     try:
         while True:
            oneline = ""
            for f in files:
                 f.seek(0, 2)
                 oneline = f.readline()
                 if not oneline:
                     continue
                 flog.write(oneline)
            if oneline:
                 flog.flush()
            else:
                 sleep(0.3)
     except Exception as e:
         print(e)
         for f in files:
             f.close()
```

This is not symbolic links, but it will output all the content from all log files to `file.log` and then will append any new lines to `file.log`.

The python process should stay there as long as the `file.log` needs to have updates.

I don’t think it’s a smart solution, but if it’s the only way for you then you have a start of a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But number fo file in my case is not fixed. It can range upto 20 or even more. I have different files like `f1X.log` `f2X.log` and many more so for `f1X` I want `f1.log` and so on.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi You can use `glob.glob("file*.log")` to get all of them in a list.

Comment: Thanks @CyrillePontvieux I am getting error. `   lines = chain(*map(lambda f: (line for line in f)))
TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.
`
have you seen this